# ¿Por que un array random me arroja undefined?

Tags: javascript

Verán cree un array que crea un texto random que coloca en un link, reemplazando los espacios por `-` pero me arroja undefined.

Este es mi código:

```
var array = ["texto 1", "text 2", "text 3", "text 4"];
 var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
 $('a').attr('href', array[random].replace(/\s/g, "-"));
```

Comment: ¿el array es creado correctamente y el valro `random` está dentro del rango del arreglo?

Comment: Los array son universales entre los lenguajes de programación: **los índices van desde** `0` **hasta** `n - 1`; donde `n` es la cantidad de elementos.

Comment: Salvo en sql donde los rownum y autoincrementales parten de 1 (aunque no necesariamente)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Los arrays en javascript parten desde el cero y tienen índices [0 ... length-1].

Tú estás haciendo un random que en ocasiones apuntará al índice [length], que no existe. (aunque esta posibilidad es minúscula y me sorprende que siempre te esté dando undefined.

Para asegurarte de no apuntar nunca al índice 4, debieras hacer:

```
var array = ["texto 1", "text 2", "text 3", "text 4"];
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (array.length-1));
$('a').attr('href', array[random].replace(/\s/g, "-"));
```

Pero esto no te va a dar un resultado equiprobable. En esa solución la posibilidad de que salga el texto 4 es ínfima.

Yo lo corregiría contemplando el caso de borde (random===array.length) y corrigiéndolo para apuntar al índice anterior:

```js
var array = ["texto 1", "text 2", "text 3", "text 4"];
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
if(random===array.length) {
   random=(array.length-1)
}
console.log(array[random].replace(/\s/,'-'));
```

PD: el nombre "array" es un muy mal nombre para un array.

Comment: +1 por: *el nombre "array" es un muy mal nombre para un array* xD.

Comment: Jajajajaja ya lo se, solo lo puse de ejemplo. xD

Comment: Y por siertó gracias por la explicación, veré si me da un resultado positivo.

Comment: Por sierto, se me olvido mencionar que el error me resalta en el `replace`. xD

Comment: Un pregunta mas, como podría generar el texto aleatorio de manera ordenada.

Comment: Por sierto  tu explicación no me funciono.

Comment: Quieres una función que reciba un número N y devuelva un arreglo de N textos?

Comment: Pon un ejemplo más cercano a la realidad. Significa que el error está en otro lado